# Safari Search field issue

Tags: html, css, safari

Search field is working perfectly on all browser's except safari, Safari is not picking the padding + height of search field which is causing the issue.

Please have a view to link:

```
techzeast.com/projects/html-current
```

Thanks indeed for your help.

Comment: did you try reset.css?

Answer (score 3):

Just add `-webkit-appearance: none` to `.search {}`

For overriding issues use `input[type="search"].search {}`
and also override `box-sizing: border-box; to box-sizing: padding-box;`

— Default User Agent Stylesheet for iOS

```
input[type="search"] {
    -webkit-appearance: searchfield; /* need to be changed */
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: try changing '.search{}' with 'input[type="search"].search {}' to overcome overriding problems

Answer (score 0):

I'm not on a Mac right now but I think it's because of the rendering of "search" input type you set.

Try to change the type of your input to "text" instead of search.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add line-height :

```
.search {
        width: 94%;
        float: left;
        border-top-left-radius: 5px;
        padding: 10px 10px;
        height: 54px;
        margin-top: 33px;
        font-size: 18px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
        line-height: 30px; // need to add
    }
```